# Configure IBMJCE Cryptography lib on Oracle Server

Tags: java, linux, oracle, tomcat

I'm a Linux newbie, and I want to configure my oracle server' JDK to use IBM JCE cryptography provider. if it was windows I used to copy the jar file into ext folder of the `JAVA_HOME/JRE/lib` folder and then include the provider in to `java.security` file. But on Linux my first problem is that I can not figure where the application server (Tomcat 7) is locating java and related configuration. there is a line printed on console of Tomcat which shows `/usr/bin/java` but there is not `ext` folder neither `java.security` there. I also have used the `find` command to find all `java.security` files located on server. I used to configure all of them but the exception on my web application still remains which says can not find IBMJCE provider. even I have set up `JAVA_HOME` variable and configured the JDK path which was being addressed by that variable but it did not work either. 
How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/java` will be a symbolic link to the real path.  To see where it points use `ls -l`.  On my machine this gives

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 15 Nov 13:22 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Note that there may be more than one symbolic link involved, in which case use `ls -l` on each link.

Comment: not an answer to the jce question. Just to "how to find java dirs in linux"?